# HTTP Request, Object/Array Destructuring

Tags: javascript, arrays, rest, api, object

I have an array of objects, that are on an api.

```
{
    "ErrorCode": 0,
    "ErrorMessage": null,
    "Warehouses": [
        {
            "Code": null,
            "Name": "Depozit Fabrica",
            "WarehouseID": "cb4fbab4-b8db-4807-a2b0-fad710f1fd9e"
        },
        {
            "Code": "3",
            "Name": "Depozit Magazin",
            "WarehouseID": "dfa08a15-e3a0-4d43-8af6-c24a9d43101c"
        },
        {
            "Code": null,
            "Name": "Depozit Ograda",
            "WarehouseID": "0dc8318d-305c-4e09-a31c-aa6fd44bf2ca"
        }
    ]
}
```

I got the "Name" of "Warehouses" showed in my DOM. These "Name" have different ID's. SO, what I'm trying to do is everytime I click on a certain "Name" object, I get its ID and further call another REST API, with this ID, that shows an assortment list for example.

```
async function getWarehouse() {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    const { Warehouses } = data;

    for (var i = 0; i < Warehouses.length; i++) {
        const dataItem = Warehouses[i].Name;
        console.log(dataItem);

        document.getElementById("depList").innerHTML += 
         `
         <ul>
           <li class="data-item">${dataItem}</li>
         </ul>
         `
...
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the value as an html attribute e.g. `data-code`, and access it in the click event handler.

```js
const data = {
  "ErrorCode": 0,
  "ErrorMessage": null,
  "Warehouses": [{
      "Code": null,
      "Name": "Depozit Fabrica",
      "WarehouseID": "cb4fbab4-b8db-4807-a2b0-fad710f1fd9e"
    },
    {
      "Code": "3",
      "Name": "Depozit Magazin",
      "WarehouseID": "dfa08a15-e3a0-4d43-8af6-c24a9d43101c"
    },
    {
      "Code": null,
      "Name": "Depozit Ograda",
      "WarehouseID": "0dc8318d-305c-4e09-a31c-aa6fd44bf2ca"
    }
  ]
};

function getWarehouse() {

  const {
    Warehouses
  } = data;

  for (var i = 0; i < Warehouses.length; i++) {
    const dataItem = Warehouses[i].Name;
    document.getElementById("depList").innerHTML +=
      `
         <ul>
           <li class="data-item" data-code="${Warehouses[i].WarehouseID}">${dataItem}</li>
         </ul>
         `;


    let dataItems = document.querySelectorAll('.data-item');

    dataItems.forEach((di) => {
      di.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.getAttribute('data-code'));

      })
    })
  }
}


getWarehouse();
```

```html
<div id="depList">

</div>
```

Comment: Aditya Bhave, how do I use the event.target.getAttribute('data-code'), as a custom parameter for my next HTTP Request? The parameter should be inside Curly Brackets {}.

Comment: Just put it inside JSON. Add more details such as request type, URL, expected input etc. if you cannot figure this out.

Comment: It's a GET request, I want to get an assortment list when clicking on a certain Warehouse, I managed to do it.  Thanks to you!

Comment: Great !! Happy to help